GraphicsCaptureItem::CreateFromVisual but my input parameter is type Microsoft.UI.Composition.Visual instead of Windows
I'm migrating from UWP to WinUI3 and I'm trying to capture a screenshot of certain element in Xaml.
auto vis = ElementCompositionPreview::GetElementVisual(m_elementToCapture);
m_item = GraphicsCaptureItem::CreateFromVisual(vis);

I'm using Microsoft version of ElementCompositionPreview::GetElementVisual, so then vis is of Microsoft.UI.Composition.Visual type, but GraphicsCaptureItem::CreateFromVisual requires Windows.UI.Composition.Visual.
Tried to cast vis to required type by using try_as, it returns null.
I'm wondering what to do in this case?

There is currently no Microsoft version of GraphicsCaptureItem::CreateFromVisual in WinUI3. It is recommended that you use RenderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync to render a snapshot of a UIElement visual tree to an image source.

The question is tagged [tag:c++]. This doesn't look like C++ code.
